# How to maintain number of elements / shrink on browser resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, resize

I am learning how to resize div elements as the browser changes size. I want my slider (see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbLxrowj/2/)) to always display 10 slides even when the browser gets smaller (see picture below).

Goal:

[image]
The only way I can think of accomplishing this is to make each list element relative to the browser size, so I tried Bootstrap's grid layout but it doesn't work. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Grid doesn't work as expected:

```
<div class="row wrapper">
  <span class="prev-slide col-md-1"><</span>
  <ul class="tab-container row col-md-10">
    <li class="col-md-1">Slide 1</li>
    <li class="col-md-1">Slide 2</li>
    <li class="col-md-1">Slide 3</li>
    <li class="col-md-1">Slide 4</li>
    <li class="col-md-1">Slide 5</li>
    <li class="col-md-1">Slide 6</li>
    <li class="col-md-1">Slide 7</li>
    <li class="col-md-1">Slide 8</li>
    <li class="col-md-1">Slide 9</li>
    <li class="col-md-1">Slide 10</li>

  </ul><span class="next-slide col-md-1">></span>
</div>
```

The JSFiddle I provided above does not have Bootstrap grid implemented as it doesn't function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the browser gets smaller you add col-sm-1 and col-xs-1 in to all class.

```
 <div class="row wrapper">
  <span class="prev-slide col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"/>
  <ul class="tab-container row col-md-10">
   <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Slide 1</li>
   <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Slide 2</li>
   <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Slide 3</li>
   <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Slide 4</li>
   <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Slide 5</li>
   <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Slide 6</li>
   <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Slide 7</li>
   <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Slide 8</li>
   <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Slide 9</li>
   <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Slide 10</li>

  </ul><span class="next-slide col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, please see the Fiddle with your solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/zbLxrowj/4/

Comment: is there anyway to make the entire div shrink is size, like literally making the div shorter and narrower when browser resizes?